# Typescript property selector

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need simple type checking based on object property which I'd like to use like this:

```
type User = { id: string, name: string }
sort<User>("name");
```

where Intellisense offers me "name" or "id" for input or shows "error" if anything else is entered.

With my current implementation `property` is not of type `string`, although I'm able to pass only `string` value.

```
sort<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(property: keyof T) {
    // how can I make 'property' string ???
    // required API object is e.g. { property: "Id", desc: true }
}
```

Here is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgVwM4gPYFsYF4YG9gwwQBOq0x4AXDCsQJYB2A5gDQEwAmUSAxtQEapUAGygBDBsAC+wYADMEDHiDqoGNVBQA8AFRhQAHiCgMOSPDADaAayhhqtRkwC61CWBhSAfAAoSZKAp7GFswVDkYHQBKakQUDDx2QmIoEARidXxCbKJScipcgKC2HMIuXmo5MWEkKCTPaVlwaBgAVVribAs6DgcQemYWGAYxdCg+gaYGpE0QLXbA3wAiEbGlqIBuIA).

Comment: `property` type is  union of   keys from T and it looks fine. Why do you want to have property with type  `string`?

Comment: I've edited my question. Because I need only single property in that method. keyof T is not requirement, its the way I've currently implemented it.

Comment: hm... Why didn't you define `sort<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(property: string) {` this way ?

Comment: Because I would have any Intellisense telling me to pass only property names of T, which is whole point of question.

Comment: I'm not sure  I understand  you. But  you can try this `sort<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(property: keyof T | string) {`

Comment: Please see attached playground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your constraint has a string indexer in actual fact the `keyof T` could still be a `number` so `keyof T` would end up being `string | number`

You can use `Extract` to arrow to just strings:

```
type Custom = {
  property: string, //ok 
  desc: boolean
}

function sort<T>(property: Extract<keyof T, string>): Custom {
    return {
      property: property,
      desc: false
    }
}

type User = { id: string, name: string }
sort<User>("name");
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgVwM4gPYFsYF4YG9gwwQBOq0x4AXDCsQJYB2A5gDQEwAmUSAxtQEapUAGygBDBsAC+wYADMEDHiDqoGNVBQA8AFQB8AChJkoFMNQCiADxDExyrQGsoYVHJg6WNW4yZ6AlNSIKBh47ITEUCAIxOr4hAlEpORUSSZmXgD0mTCojjDhCVy81HJiwkhQhTIyoJCwAKqVxNh4MHQc1LS+Xgxi6FBdPswwMkiaIFpNpoYARH0Ds-4A3EA)